# Why the new value is not dispatched?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to set new values by redux but a single key "status" every time after dispatching as an empty string. I don't know what is it and why every time empty maybe somebody know solution?
[image]

call action and dispatch code:

```
store.dispatch(actionSetNewResponseFilterValues({
        active_level: "1",
        query_in: ["0"],
        status: ["15"]})
    );
```

action method:

```
export const actionSetNewResponseFilterValues = (newValues) => {
    return {
        type: SET_RESP_FILT_VALS,
        newValues
    }
}
```

and code in reducer:

```
case SET_RESP_FILT_VALS:
        case LOAD_RESP_FILT_VALS:
            return {
                ...state,
                filter: {
                    ...state.filter,
                    newValues: {
                        ...state.filter.newValues,
                        ...action.newValues
                    }
                }
            }
```

#udpated
when in reducer coding whithout destructuring-assignment:

```
case SET_RESP_FILT_VALS:
        case LOAD_RESP_FILT_VALS:
            return {
                ...state,
                filter: {
                    ...state.filter,
                    newValues: action.newValues
                }
            }
```

in dispatching I see an empty status key:
[image]